# how to use translations in prestashop controllers?

Tags: php, controller, translation, prestashop

normally templates have a smarty function like this: `{l s="string"}` while modules just use `$this->l('string');`. On controllers the l() function seems not to be available, so qhat if I want to set up some text to be translated from backoffice?

Answer (score 3):

It is available in controllers You just need to add module object in play.

You should do this

```
$this->module->l('Your string to translate', 'file_name');
```

For example if you are in `validation.php` your `'file_name'` should be just `'validation'`

So full example looks like this

```
$this->module->l('Your string to translate', 'validation');
```

Answer (score 0):

in both cases there is used methods from class `Translate` e.g. for module translations `Translate::getModuleTranslation(...)`, you can check `classes/Transalte.php` and find there static method `getAdminTranslation(...)` and in AdminController child classes available `l()` method that use it.

Comment: Mmm, but what about frontend controllers?

Comment: I just not sure why you need to translate something in frontend controller, why not just e.g. assign needed "string" to smarty variable in controller and then `{l s="string"}` in template? by default I see no ways to do it

Comment: we developers always have a need, if we ask :) In this case, I need to programmatically build strings based on several variables and (only) then assign them to smarty vars. I don't see ways, just as you, though. I think you're right: we can't. But it's quite strange: I don't see the point in making l() function available for modules but not for frontend controllers. Both assign smarty vars, so both need it. Bah...

Comment: yeah, just I do not saw full task. But again, if you really need it you can always write controllers `l()` yourself :)

Comment: Yes, that's true, still quite annoying since I should also add a translation page to the backoffice. So instead, I'll fall back to dummy things like `if(current lang is x) do x`. Not so good (especially for my client..) but faster. :)